# sql table with custom columns and data in the cells

Tags: sql, sqlite

I want to create table in sql, where rows and columns would be some values, and in the (i, j) cell there would be an according value. Something like that:

```
----------------------------------------
| receipt/ingr | apple | banana | cream
----------------------------------------
| cake         | 0     | 1      | 1
| salad        | 1     | 1      | 0
----------------------------------------
```

So that 1 means that recipe contains ingredient. The problem is, that I have large number of ingredients & recipes, so that I can't manually write the names in the select. I have no idea how to create this format.

The tables I have:

```
Receipts (id, name)
Ingredients (id, name)
Receipt_ingredient (id, receipt_id, ingredient_id)
```

How can I do it? Thanks in advance

Comment: search for pivot

Comment: This is called dynamic pivoting.  I would suggest that you do it at the application layer.